# Continuity of the Frechet Derivative, A result by Krasnosel'skii

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

In the book *Critical Point Theory and Hamiltonian Systems* by Jean Mawhin and Michel Willem one considers a linear functional of the form

$$\langle \phi(u),v\rangle = \int_{0}^{T}\Big[\left\langle D_xL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t)),v(t)\right\rangle+\left\langle D_yL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t)),\dot{v}(t)\right\rangle\Big]dt$$
where $u$ and $v$ are members of the space of $T$-period Sobolev functions: $W_T^{1,p}$ and $L$ possesses some integrability conditions stated at the end of the question. The map $v\mapsto \langle\phi(u),v\rangle$ is the directional (Gateaux) derivative of a non-linear functional. **One wants to show that the non-linear functional is Frechet differentiable and so one must show that $u\mapsto \phi(u)$ which is a map from $W_{T}^{1,p}$ to $(W_T^{1,p})^\ast$ is continuous.**

However in the proof of continuity they only refer to a result by Krasnosel'skii.

> **Properties of $L$.**
>
> $L:[0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^N\times \mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$
>   is such that $(x,y)\mapsto L(t,x,y)$ is $C^1$ for a.e. $t$. There are
>   functions $a\in C(\mathbb{R}^+,\mathbb{R}^+)$, $b\in
>  L^1(0,T;\mathbb{R}^N)$ and $c\in L^q(0,T;\mathbb{R}^+)$ where
>   $p^{-1}+q^{-1} = 1$ such that \begin{align*} |L(t,x,y)|&\leq
>  a(|x|)(b(t)+|y|^p)\\ |D_xL(t,x,y)|&\leq a(|x|)(b(t)+|y|^p)\\
>  |D_yL(t,x,y)| &\leq a(|x|)(c(t)+|y|^{p-1}). 
> \end{align*}

**My attempt**

I want to apply something like Lebesgue's Dominated Convergence Theorem however I don't think this is possible in this case:

Suppose $u_k\rightarrow u$ in $W_T^{1,p}$ then $\|u_k-u\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$. Cauchy Schwarz implies that
\begin{align*}
|\langle\phi(u_k)-\phi(u),v\rangle| & \leq \int_{0}^{T}|D_xL(t,u_k(t),\dot{u}_k(t))-D_xL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))||v|dt\\
& + \int_{0}^{T}|D_yL(t,u_k(t),\dot{u}_k(t)-D_yL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))||\dot{v}|dt\\
& \leq \|v\|_\infty\int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^p)-a(|u|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p)\Big|dt\\
& + \|\dot{v}\|_p\left(\int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^{p-1})-a(|u(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^{p-1})\Big|^{q}\right)^{1/q}
\end{align*}

Now I can bound both norms in $v$ by the Sobolev norm however how can one show that the integrals converge to $0$?

---

Maybe one can use that every subsequence has itself a subsequence which converges and that such a limit is unique:

By a result of Riesz we can always extract a subsequence of $u_k$ such that $\dot{u}_k(t)\rightarrow \dot{u}(t)$ for almost every $t$. Since
$$\Big|a(|u_k|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^p)-a(|u|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p)\Big|\leq a(|u_k|)|\dot{u}_k(t)^p-\dot{u}(t)^p|+|a(|u_k|)-a(|u|)||b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p|$$
which converges to zero in $L^1$ by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem since we assumed that $\dot{u}_k\rightarrow \dot{u}$ pointwise for almost every $t$.

Comment: Dominated convergence is the way to go. Note that the proofs to extract a.e. pointwise converging subsequences also produce the common upper bound that is necessary for the application of dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: See Theorem 4.9. in Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations by Haim Brezis

Comment: Ok Thanks, But the argument I gave should be ok right?

Comment: You need to establish a dominating function for all those expressions

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean I will look into this

Comment: Ok Thanks I see now how to solve this problem, many thanks. This was not pointed out in the book I used for measure theory in class but the proof was a consequence of something we showed, so this was very nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $u_k\rightarrow u$ in $W_T^{1,p}$ implies that $\|u_k-u\|_{L^\infty}\rightarrow 0$. So in particular this value stays bounded. Furthermore by a result proven by Riesz we can extract a subsequence such that the derivatives converges pointwise. Assume that this has been done without changing the notation. Furthermore one can also choose the subsequence such that there is a dominating function $h\in L^p$ such that $\dot{u}_k(t)\leq h(t)$ (see Theorem 4.9 in Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations by Hair Brezis, reference courtesy of @daw).

Cauchy Schwarz implies that
    \begin{align*}
  |\langle\varphi'(u_k)-\varphi'(u),v\rangle| & \leq \int_{0}^{T}|D_xL(t,u_k(t),\dot{u}_k(t))-D_xL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))||v|dt\\
  & + \int_{0}^{T}|D_yL(t,u_k(t),\dot{u}_k(t)-D_yL(t,u(t),\dot{u}(t))||\dot{v}|dt\\
  & \leq \|v\|_{L^\infty}\int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^p)-a(|u|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p)\Big|dt\\
  & + \|\dot{v}\|_{L^p}\left(\int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^{p-1})-a(|u(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^{p-1})\Big|^{q}dt\right)^{1/q}.
 \end{align*}
    Clearly we can bound both of the norms in $v$ by a multiple of $\|v\|_{W_T^{1,p}}$ using Soblev and Poincar\'{e}'s inequalities so all that remains is to show that the integrals converge to $0$. Since $\|u_k\|_{L^\infty}$ is bounded we can find $M>0$ such that
    \begin{align*}
  \Big|a(|u_k|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^p)-a(|u|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p)\Big|&\leq \underbrace{a(|u_k|)}_{\leq M}|\dot{u}_k(t)^p-\dot{u}(t)^p|+\underbrace{|a(|u_k|)-a(|u|)|}_{\leq M}|b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p|\\
  &\leq M\Big[|h(t)|^p+|\dot{u}(t)|^p\Big]+M|b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p|\in L^1.
 \end{align*}
    Since also the pointwise limit is $0$ we conclude by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem that 
    \begin{equation*}
  \int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^p)-a(|u|)(b(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^p)\Big|dt\rightarrow 0.
 \end{equation*}
    We now consider the second equation. By rewriting similarly to before it is clear that the pointwise limit is $0$. Since
    \begin{equation*}
  a(|u_k(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^{p-1})\leq M(c(t)+h(t)^{p-1})\in L^q 
 \end{equation*}
    we conclude again by Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem that we may take the pointwise limit obtaining that
    \begin{equation*}
  \left(\int_{0}^{T}\Big|a(|u_k(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}_k(t)|^{p-1})-a(|u(t)|)(c(t)+|\dot{u}(t)|^{p-1})\Big|^{q}dt\right)^{1/q}\rightarrow 0. 
 \end{equation*}
    This shows that
    \begin{equation*}
  \frac{|\langle\varphi'(u_k)-\varphi'(u),v\rangle|}{\|v\|_{W_T^{1,p}}} \leq \epsilon(k)\rightarrow 0
 \end{equation*}
    as $k\rightarrow \infty$ independently of $v$ so that $\|\varphi(u_k)-\varphi(u)\|\leq \epsilon(k)\rightarrow 0$.